# In linux, how to save only the command into file without output

Tags: linux

I just want to save only the command into file, without the long output. For example, i type `ls`, terminal output `a.txt b.txt`, if i type `ls > command.txt`, the content of `command.txt` will be

```
a.txt
b.txt
command.txt
```

But what i want is :

```
ls
```

Can we achieve this ?

Comment: I assume you know about the existing history file (e.g., `.bash_history`, `.zsh_history`) but that it's not what you're looking for?

Comment: @frippe  I think go to `~/.bash_history` to look for commands have some shortcomings: 1. The command will be written to `~/.bash_history` only when I close the terminal. 2. can not output to the specified directory and file. So what i expect is to output the commands immediately to the specified directory and file.

Comment: Those shortcomings can be overcome by 1) `history -w` (there are also ways to write the command immediately to the history file) 2) `HISTFILE` can be set to an arbitrary path

Comment: But `HISTFILE`(or `~/.bash_history`) mixes many other earlier commands, i expect the output file has pure commands that typed in current terminal.

Comment: AFAICT, when the shell is started, it caches the history found in the currently set `HISTFILE`. If you change `HISTFILE` for the interactive shell, when you write the history to the new file, the old history will be written too. Either you can start the shell as `HISTFILE=<some_path> bash` or you should be able to run `history -c` _after_ you've changed `HISTFILE` which will clear the history list. The documentation doesn't specifically say anything about it, but when testing it on my machine, the previous `HISTFILE` is unchanged, so you should not be in for any surprises.

Answer (score 0):

All shells store the history of commands run in dotfiles in the home directory.
Assuming you're using bash, i think you should be looking at the `~/.bash_history` file